# Selenium RC drops error when it tries open the popup

Tags: selenium, hta

When selenium tries to open popup window I'm getting JS error permission denied in file

> file:///C:/DOCUME~1//LOCALS~1/Temp/customProfileDir8708f7f69e14482ba857f4b2e74775c1/core/RemoteRunner.hta

So this break script execution, could you assist? I saw a related topic at MSDN and openqa but didn't find resolution that could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this error. In the end it was because I was running IE in 'Offline' mode. Open the File menu and make sure that "Work Offline" does not have a tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated a section about that in the Selenium docs. The website build is not working right now, so if you go to the site you will find the old version.

I'll paste the raw text here, I think your case is the second: JS trying to access sections that are still not loaded, so your solution would be a waitForPopUp command:

> Why am I getting a permission denied
>   error?
>
> The most common reason for this error
>   is that your session is attempting to
>   violate the same-origin policy by
>   crossing domain boundaries (e.g.,
>   accesses a page from  http://domain1
>   and then accesses a page from
>   http://domain2) or switching protocols
>   (moving from http://domainX to
>   https://domainX). For this to be
>   solved, try using the Heightened
>   Privileges Browsers if you're working
>   with the Proxy Injection browsers.
>   This is covered in some detail in the
>   tutorial. Make sure you read the
>   sections about The Same Origin Policy
>   and Proxy Injection carefully.
>
> If the previous situation was not your
>   case, it can also occur when
>   JavaScript  attempts to look at
>   objects which are not yet available
>   (before the page has   completely
>   loaded), or tries to look at objects
>   which are no longer available  (after
>   the page has started to be unloaded).
>   This is most typically encountered 
>   with AJAX pages which are working with
>   sections of a page or subframes that
>   load  and/or reload independently of
>   the larger page. For this type of
>   problem, it is common that the error
>   is intermittent. Often it is
>   impossible to reproduce the   problem
>   with a debugger because the trouble
>   stems from race conditions which  are
>   not reproducible when the debugger's
>   overhead is added to the system. Try
>   first adding a static pause to make
>   sure this is the situation and then 
>   moving on to the waitFor kind of
>   commands.

Comment: Santi, thx for fast answer but these solutions didn't help. I'have added delays but permission denied still appear. After I manually press the yes/no at error I'm getting popup but script execution breaks. In main window I'm also have content the same as in popup. If I do this scenario manually content in main window doesn't changes after opening the popup.